# How do I maintain (or clean up) pixel perfect fonts in CSS/HTML in Chrome (or any browser) and on any OS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am creating both an electron app and a website that uses two specific pixel fonts, however, they appear extra blurry when using a CSS-powered scanline effect that I found while poking around on Google, however, even when I remove the CSS/class from the equation, the text is still SLIGHTLY blurry.  At that point, I've got two problems, though not sure how related they actually are...

Example 1: No CSS scanlines active...

[image: Font Rendering without CSS scanlines, still semi blurry]

Example 2 & 3: CSS scanlines active...

[image: Font rendering blurry with CSS scanlines]
[image: Example 2]

Here's the CSS scanline code...

```
/* Scanline CSS */
.scanlines {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .scanlines:before, .scanlines:after {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
  }
  .scanlines:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 2147483649;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.755);
    opacity: 0.75;
    animation: scanline 6s linear infinite;
  }
  .scanlines:after {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2147483648;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 51%);
    background-size: 100% 2px;
    animation: none;
  }
  /* ANIMATE UNIQUE SCANLINE */
  @keyframes scanline {
    0% {
      transform: translate3d(0, 200000%, 0);
    }
  }
  @keyframes scanlines {
    0% {
      background-position: 0 50%;
    }
  }
```

In the first example, the text has faint ghosting and honestly doesn't look terrible.  However, I like the super clean look of a pixel font, so it's going to continue to nag at me until I find a way to fix it.  If it *can* be fixed.

In the second example, the text displays *even blurrier* when the scanline effect is active.  This appears to happen even if the scanlines are in an entirely different (and un-nested) `div`.  Does it have anything to do with the `transform` rule?  I vaguely remember seeing a mention about it but I can't find anything about it while I'm writing up this question. (go figure... )

I tried using `font-smooth` and `-webkit-font-smoothing`, to no avail, even after finding posts on here, Reddit, and various articles/blogs advising of this practice to force smoothing/jagged edges.  Further research led me to understand this only functions on Mac; absolutely nothing happens on Windows due to how text is rendered with certain toolkits or something.

The fonts I am using are TTF fonts that are designed to look like the pixel fonts in the MegaMan Battle Network series.  My project uses these two fonts extensively, and as I continue working on it, other pixel fonts from the game in TTF format may be used.  I don't need anti-aliasing for the fonts, and I'm not expecting to render any graphics that need it either (If I do zoom in on certain graphics it might make it prettier, but it's not a big deal, so if I can turn it off globally on this page or force nearest-neighbor, then I'm fine with that, assuming it doesn't break how the fonts look so far).

One solution I thought of was to find a tool to convert the TTF files to a FON file or something else, however, I remember having some issues converting the fonts in the past, so I'm hesitant to try it again.  That said, if you look at the first example, the fonts render *alright*; and at normal 100% zoom, the fonts look beautiful with minimal ghosting, however, because I now know this quirk is an issue in my project, **I want it to look *pristine***.  Worst case scenario I can give it a rest, tell myself to suck it up, and deal with it.  *I know I won't be happy but whatever. You can't always get what you want.  Just hoping if I keep trying sometimes, I'll find that I get what I need.*

Another solution that I thought of is to go after the CSS scanline effect, however, I have no clue what to do.  I remember reading something about transforms making text blurry, but none of the text is under a `transform` function; the only stuff with a `transform` is the scanlines.  And I already isolated the div getting the scanline treatment from the rest of the content... see the code below:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainBG scanlines"></div>
    <div id="mainArea">
        <div id="mapDisplay"></div>
        <div id="copyrightInfo">Game (C) Capcom.  Map (C) Mega Boy (<a href="mailto:megaboy@sympatico.ca">megaboy@sympatico.ca</a>)</div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebarArea">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul id="sidebarTabs">
...
...
...
the rest of my HTML goes here
...
...
...
</body>
```

Note how the `div` with the `scanlines` class is empty, and the rest of the content is in its own stuff.  I cut off the rest of the code, but tags are closed appropriately and such.  I was thinking of replacing the CSS with a transparent background and instead making it flicker, but the effect isn't what I want.  I found the CSS code above, and I fell in love with the effect.  And I know as soon as I remove the `scanlines` class, the extra blurry effect gets toned down to the first example image...

If I can fix the extra blurriness by tweaking the CSS scanline code, I'm fine with that compromise.  If I can fix both issues, even better, but I'm stumped and only want to use the solutions I outlined as a last resort only.

I am absolutely willing to use some janky sus javascript code.  ***Do your worst.***  I value this looking crisp and clean over my sanity.

...Maybe not entirely, but the programmer voice in me is telling me it's happy with how this project looks so far.  The designer "Karen" voice in me, however, is yelling even louder and is currently winning the argument.